# Hangs on "Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ... "

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Hangs on "Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ... "  when I am trying to install docker, or I am tying run

```
 sudo apt autoremove
```

in `Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS`. How I can fix it?